# find sum of Boolean values JavaScript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects, typescript2.0

Hi i am trying to find the sum of Boolean values in the object array in JavaScript

My json like be

```
var myoBj = [{
  "id": 1,
  "day": 1,
  "status": true
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "day": 1,
  "status": false
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "day": 1,
  "status": false
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "day": 3,
  "status": false
}];
```

i want the sum of all **status** values using reduce function in JavaScript/ typescript

i want to show overall **status as true** only when all status are true else it should be false

Comment: Sum of boolean, what you mean ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan i want to show overall **status as true** only when all status are true else it should be false

Comment: Why `.reduce()`..? There is an array functor especially tailored for this job called `.every()`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var result = myObj.reduce((sum, next) => sum && next.status, true);
```

This should return true, if every value is true.

Comment: This solution seems to be neat and simple , Thanks Balint

Comment: @SathyaV Maybe neat and simple, but can't beat `myObj.every(item => item.status)`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to sum lets say, `day` items value depending on the `status` flag, this can looks like:

```
var result = myObj.reduce((res, item) => item.status ? res + item.day : res, 0);
```

#### Update 1

For overall status in case of all statuses are true you should use every method:

```
var result = myObj.every(item => item.status);
```

Comment: i want to show overall **status as true** only when all status are true else it should be false

Comment: Thanks TSV for the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you must use `reduce` you can take advantage of the fact that `x*false == 0`, and so you can do the following:

```js
const myObj=[{id:1,day:1,status:true},{id:2,day:1,status:false},{id:3,day:1,status:false},{id:4,day:3,status:false}],

res = !!myObj.reduce((bool, {status}) => bool*status, true);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's crazy, I didn't know multiplying booleans returned 0, 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.some` with predicate `a => !a.status` or `Array.every` with predicate `a => a.status`.

Either of them will short-circuit if you find a mismatch, while `Array.reduce` will not.