# Disable a button based on object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to disable my button inside my components whenever one of my object property is set to true.

```
      className="button save"
      disabled={this.props.validationObject.reduce(
        (sum, next) => sum && next,
        true
      )}
    >
```

Here is my validation object

```
validationObject: {
    Title: true,
    IBCSegmentId: true,
    CountryId: true,
    localCOMPageTitle: true
  }
```

Note that it only take 1 true for my disbale to disables is that possible? I tried "reduce" but it didnt worked. I was trying to copy what they did here

[find sum of Boolean values JavaScript object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739710/find-sum-of-boolean-values-javascript-object-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object here, so directly using `reduce` or any other array method does not work in your situation. You can use `Object.keys` and `some` to get the desired result.

```js
const obj = {
    Title: false,
    IBCSegmentId: true,
    CountryId: false,
    localCOMPageTitle: false,
};

const isTrue = Object.keys( obj ).some( el => obj[el] );

console.log( isTrue );
```

```js
const obj = {
  Title: false,
  IBCSegmentId: true,
  CountryId: false,
  localCOMPageTitle: false
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const isTrue = Object.keys(obj).some(el => obj[el]);
    return (
      <button disabled={isTrue}>Foo</button>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. @Ruzihm's answer provides an answer using `reduce`. So, it deserves an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()` to reduce the values, and also, you need to reduce with an or (`||`) operation so that it's only false if all of them are false.

```js
var validationObject = {
    Title: false,
    IBCSegmentId: false,
    CountryId: false,
    localCOMPageTitle: false
  };

var shouldDisable = Object.values(validationObject).reduce(
       (sum, next) =>sum || next
      );
   
console.log(shouldDisable);


validationObject = {
    Title: true,
    IBCSegmentId: false,
    CountryId: false,
    localCOMPageTitle: false
  };

shouldDisable = Object.values(validationObject).reduce(
       (sum, next) =>sum || next
      );
console.log(shouldDisable);
```